# Count number of times two elements in array are less than or equal to a sum value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this JS function that finds the number of times two elements equal to a sum value. I am trying to modify this so that the condition isn't only when the two elements are equal to sum, but when it's less than the sum value as well.

```
var array = [-10, -8, -1, 0, 1, 6, 10];
var sum = 16;

function findLessThanOrEqualSum(array, sum){
  var count = 0;
  var map = {};
  for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    var temp = sum - array[i]; //This right here only accounts for when two elements = sum

    if(temp >= 0 && map[temp]){
      console.log(sum + " " + array[i] + " " + temp);
      count++;
    }
    map[array[i]] = true;
  }
  console.log(count);
}

findLessThanOrEqualSum(array, sum);
```

How would I change this condition `var temp = sum - array[i];` so that it accounts for the instances `temp` is `<=` `sum - array[i];`?

I've tried assigned a second `temp` variable that will hold all the values for when `temp <= sum - array[i];` but I was not successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: given the above array, what would be the output if you also wanted less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it in a very convoluted way. Just use nested loops that add two array elements, and test if they're less than the sum.

```js
var array = [-10, -8, -1, 0, 1, 6, 10, 11, 8, 9];
var sum = 16;

function findLessThanOrEqualSum(array, sum) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] + array[j] < sum) {
        console.log(sum + " " + array[i] + " " + array[j]);
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
}

findLessThanOrEqualSum(array, sum);
```

The way you're doing it works for the equal condition because you can look for a specific key in `map`. But there's no specific thing to look for when you have an comparison condition.